# How to load different nibs of collectionivew cell in collectionview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableview, in this tableview i have four rows, in each row i added a collection view programatically and i check that if its my first row i should register 1st nib of collection view cell, if its my 2nd row, i should register 2nd nib of collection view cell and so on and than i simply reloads the collection view. I used the below code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID"];

if(cell==nil){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

UICollectionView *collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
collectionView.dataSource=self;
collectionView.delegate=self;


if (indexPath.row==0) {
    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"QuotesCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"quotes"];

} else if (indexPath.row==1){

    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AlphabeticalWiseCategoriresCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"alphabets"];

} else if (indexPath.row==2){

    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DaysCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"days"];

}else if(indexPath.row==3){

    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LifeAspectsCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"life"];
}

[collectionView reloadData];
return cell;

}
```

My problem/question is how could i come to know with which collection view nib i have to deal with in following delegates, because here i have to specify the same reuse identifier that i have used while registering nib with collection view ?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


}
```

My Second problem is how could i detect which tableview row's collection view cell's is clicked since i have different collection view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, why do you not use static table view? If you hardcode every cell, I think it will be good enhancement.
Next about your problem, iOS provides every UIView tag property. 
If you remake your table to static table, then you will can set tag property via InterfaceBuilder. If not:

```
UICollectionView *collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
collectionView.dataSource=self;
collectionView.delegate=self;
collectionView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  switch collectionView.tag {
  case 0:
    ...
    break
  case 1:
    ...
    break
  }
}
```

And your can use this approach to resolve your second problem

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me what have you added in

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the `collectionView` you created each time, say, in an `array`. So the index of each `collectionView` in the `array` will be equal to the `indexPath.row`. By retrieve the index of the `collectionView` parameter in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you could know which `collectionView` you are dealing with, as well as the `UICollectionViewCell`.